# How to change the header comment for swift file

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-template

Custom the header comment for every project.

I created a `plist` file called `IDETemplateMacros.plist` and it's custom the header comment for all project but I need custom header for specific project, not for all the project and revert the custom text macro to default.

```
//
//  CategoryViewController.swift
//  ToDoey
//
//  Created by Swetha on 28/01/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Swetha. All rights reserved.
//
```

to

```
//Hey..CategoryViewController.swift
```

I deleted the IDETemplateMacros.plist but it doesn't revert the text macro to default.

I expect the default text macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the text macros globally, or for an individual workspace or project. You can also decide to keep the macros for a single user or share it for all users.

The full list of locations that Xcode searches, in order of priority:

### - Project - single user

```
<ProjectName>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/[username].xcuserdatad/
```

### - Project - shared by all users

```
<ProjectName>.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/
```

### - Workspace - single user

```
<WorkspaceName>.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[username].xcuserdatad/
```

### - Workspace - shared by all users

```
<WorkspaceName>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
```

### - Globally for Xcode

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/
```

I don't remember what was the default template but you can make a template in anyway you like using `textMacros`:

```
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PACKAGENAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  ___COPYRIGHT___
//
```

There are some other `textMacro`s if you like more customization, but these are enough for making something like the default one.

Comment: how can i map my terminal to this <ProjectName>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/[username].xcuserdatad/

Comment: Instead of <projectname>.xcodeproj put path to it or drag the file in terminal and add extra route